# Understanding ASPasswordCredential during sign in with Apple

Tags: ios, swift, sign-in-with-apple

I am trying to learn how to use Sign in with Apple. Looking for Juice demo app used by Apple in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple) everything is clear except the case where the returned credential is ASPasswordCredential.

It explains in this case the user made the authentication with username and password and these data were stored in keychain. I am not able to get a use case for this scenario and I am not able to understand in which real case it is called, because every time I try to log in the controller shows me the authentication with fingerprint in both cases it is a first registration or not.

Could you help to understand it or let me know how could I reproduce this?

Please note I am using a real device

Comment: I have the same problem. I think this is something for migration for older apps that might have had username/password in the iCloud Keychain? the documentation is really lacking on this ;(

Comment: Yes, you are right about documentation. What i have understood is that this scenario is not applied if the log in with apple is trigged. So if you are making the log in with apple, you will always use it without firing keychain, but if you have previously used it and try to compile a user/pass form, it should suggest you credentials (stored in keychain). Feel free to let us know if you discover more.